# How to override Salesforce Home tab with custom Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, home-page-layout

I have developed a custom Visualforce Page. I want to add the VF page to the Home Tab, ie. when I will login into Salesforce automatically that custom VF page should be displayed.

Please suggest me with required navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can not override entire Home tab by the visualforce page.

Though, you can create home page component and use your visualforce in the component and finally add the component into this homepage.

Otherwise create a custom visualforce tab and rename that tab as 'Home` and use this in your app.

Navigate to your App and select the Default Landing tab.

[image: landing tab]

Answer (score 1):

You may add the VF page as a section of the home page [a bit like inline VF].

Here are the steps to follow :

1. You should create a Home Page Component.

   > Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Component

   You must create `New` under `Custom Components`.

---

2. Then you may create a new layout for your home page.

   > Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Layouts > New

   Add the desired components to your layout.

---

3. Last step is to assign the new layout to specific profiles.

   > Setup > Customize > Home > Home Page Layouts > Page Layout Assignment

   Note: You'll not see the page/layout until you assign it to the profiles you want.